# Merge multiple csv files in s3 directory to one file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, csv

I have 100+ csv files avaialable in my s3-bucket/20230405
How can I merge these file and generate a single report or final file result.csv

Comment: You use Java and the AWS SDK to write a program to perform this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and working for me

```
private static final AmazonS3 S3_CLIENT = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(S3_REGION).build();

private final String REPORT_FILE_NAME = "Report";

public void Report(@NonNull final String s3KeyInput) {
        List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummaryList = getS3ObjectSummaries(s3KeyInput, S3_BUCKET, S3_CLIENT)

;

        List<S3Object> s3objectList = s3ObjectSummaryList
            .stream()
            .map(
                s3Obj ->
                    S3_CLIENT.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET, s3Obj.getKey()))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> s3ObjectStringList = transformS3ObjectToString(s3objectList);

        File csvFile = getMergedCSVFile(REPORT_FILE_NAME, s3ObjectStringList);

        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = getPutObjectRequest(REPORT_FILE_NAME, csvFile);

        uploadFileToS3(putObjectRequest);

    }

    @NotNull
    private static File getMergedCSVFile(String resultFileName,
                                         List<String> s3ObjectStringList) {
        File csvFile = null;
        final String FILE_HEADER = "Name, DisplayName, Name" + "\r\n";
        try {
            csvFile = File.createTempFile(resultFileName, ".csv");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(csvFile);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
            bw.write(FILE_HEADER);
            for (String str : s3ObjectStringList) {
                bw.write(str + "\r\n");
            }
            bw.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while Merging CSV", e);
        }
        return csvFile;
    }

    @NotNull
    private static List<String> transformS3ObjectToString(List<S3Object> s3objectList) {
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (S3Object s3Object : s3objectList) {
            final InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            strList.addAll(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            try {
                reader.close();
                streamReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return strList;
    }

    private static List<S3ObjectSummary> getS3ObjectSummaries(final String s3Key,
                                                              final String s3Bucket,
                                                              @NotNull final AmazonS3 amazonS3
    ) {
        ObjectListing s3ObjectList = amazonS3.listObjects(s3Bucket, s3Key);
        return s3ObjectList.getObjectSummaries();
    }
```